# How to get compression ratio of OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, log-files, compression

With my botnet I crawled the entire internet but I didn't found anything.

I'm running an OpenVPN server on Debian with *LZ4-v2 compression* enabled and about 5 Clients. Now I wonder where it is possible to catch the actual compression ratio, like factor 0.97 or something comparable.

Is there anyway to get this value? I would prefer simple ways, but if there is no other I would try the hard one.

Hope You see my little problem and You can give me some advices,

Greetings Julian

Answer (score 1):

Perform two packet captures (making sure to include full the full packets), one matching the encrypted stream and one matching the unencrypted stream, then compare sizes. That will give you a rough, but likely close-enough ratio calculation.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but how do I do that?

Comment: You do some research on how to perform packet captures. This site isn't somewhere to seek tutorials - your job is to figure out things like this. We're just here to point you in the right direction.